# Enquiry on union of countable set is countable

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading principle of mathematical analysis by Walter Rudin.  And saw the proof of union of countable set is also countable. According that proof they have written elements of the sets in a sequence in the following way
$x_{11};x_{12},x_{21};x_{13},x_{22},x_{31};...... $. Where $x_{mn} $ is the $m $th set's $n$the element

And giving the argument if two sets have same elements they will  appear twice and that's why we can enumerate them. My question is how can we assign different integer value to same element. To prove one-one correspondence between two elements.

Comment: You maybe need a Schröder–Bernstein theorem. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

This proof gives a surjection from the natural numbers to your union $U$ (i.e. a mapping which covers every element of $U$ at least once). This is actually enough to conclude that $U$ is countable, so a lot of proofs will just do this -- it is often simpler than finding a one-to-one correspondence (bijection) explicitly.

The reason is that, provided $U$ is infinite, you can use a surjection $f:\mathbb N\to U$ to construct a bijection $g:\mathbb N\to U$ as follows. For each $u\in U$ there is a value $\min\{n\in\mathbb N:f(n)=u\}$ (call this $h(u)$). These values are all different. Now for each $u\in U$ we can compute $g(u)=|\{v\in U:h(v)<h(u)\}|$ (this is finite since it is at most $h(u)$). If $u\neq v$ then $h(u)\neq h(v)$, so one of the corresponding sets is strictly contained in the other, so $g(u)\neq g(v)$. It is also easy to check that every natural number* is $g(u)$ for some $u$ (provided $U$ is infinite; if it is finite then this will give a bijection to the first $n$ natural numbers).

Basically what this is doing is taking the sequence you started with but only keeping the first occurrence of each element, then renumbering.

*I'm taking $\mathbb n=\{0,1,...\}$; if you want to start at $1$ replace the $<$ by $\leq$ in the definition of $g$.

Comment: Sorry but I am bit confused how is it working. Can u elaborate it with an example when two elements have same example

Comment: Say you've constructed a sequence that contains everything in your union, but some things more than once. It might start a,b,b,c,d,a,e,... Then you say a first appears in place 0, b first appears in place 1, c in place 3, d in place 4, e in place 5. Now you can construct a new sequence which has the same things once each: there are 0 things that first appear before a, so put a in place 0; there are 3 things that first appear before d, so put d in place 4, etc. That gives you the sequence starting a,b,c,d,e... - it removes all duplicates and moves everything else forward to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. But what about other a and b. Where are they